# Необработанное исключение типа "NumberFormatException" при конвертации строки в число

Tags: c#

При нажатии на ПУСК вылетает из программы.

[image: Запуск]

Делал другой тип конвертации но результат либо перестает делать расчеты 
либо просто выбивает ту же ошибку. (Если поля textbox заполнены работает нормально).

[image: Код программы]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int t1, t3, t4;
    double t2, t5, t6, t7, t8 = 1000.0, t9 = 1000.0, t10 = 100.0, t11 = 500.0;
    t1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 
    t2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    t3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text); 
    t4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text); 
    t5 = (t1 / t9); 
    t6 = (t2 / t8); 
    t7 = (t5 + t6); 

    textBox5.Text = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}Vol={4}_OpI={5}", t7, "clrRed", 1, 0, t3, t4); // вывод результата в пятый textbox
}
```

Comment: А не логично ли, что если там пустая строка или например "привет" написано, то в число оно не сконвертируется? Поясните в чем вы видите проблему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перед тем как работать с данными, полученными извне (введенные пользователем, полученные из другой системы), их нужно *валидировать*.

В вашем случае вы пытаетесь пустую строчку привести к числу. Естественно это не работает. Также пользователь может ввести в поле строку "qwerty" -- это тоже не сработает.

Валидация бывает двух типов: клиентская и серверная. Реализовывать желательно обе. Клиентская валидация заключается в том, что вы просто не даете ввести пользователю в текстбокс что-то кроме цифр. Это реализуется с помощью подписки на событие нажатия клавиши и проверки нажатых клавиш. Серверная валидация заключается в том, чтобы проверять, что присланные строки -- это валидные числа. Это можно сделать с помощью "мягких" версий соответствующих методов, которые не выбрасывают исключение и позволяют узнать, успешно ли прошла конвертация: `Int32.TryParse()`, `DateTime.TryParse()` и т.д. Соответственно ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
int t1;
if (!Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out t1))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Введите число");
}

// дальше можно работать с t1
// аналогично для других переменных
```

Отдельно при конвертации стоит обратить внимание на культуру.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее про культуру? Вы имеете в виду специфические для разных стран способы записывать числа и даты?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, в России деситичный разделитель - запятая. В большинстве других стран - точка.

Comment: Немножко не к месту у вас про клиентскую и серверную валидацию. Она имеет смысл когда у вас есть клиент и сервер, тут же очевидно отдельное приложение.

Comment: отдельное... но направление в валидации верное так что пойду пороюсь в сети или может кто еще ответ бросит

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: В принципе, можно считать UI клиентом, а логику — сервером. И применять оба способа в соответствующих местах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, разделители в числах и форматы дат разные.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin @NickVolynkin я указал общую схему. Данные случай, конечно, вырожден, но и в нем "клиентом" можно считать UI, а "сервером" -- логику, которая принимает параметры от UI. То, что у автора эта логика размещена в `Button1_Click`, не отменяет такого разделения. В случае же отдельного клиента и сервера такой подход еще и минимизирует MITM-атаки.

Comment: @andreycha хм. Ну тогда можно и "UI" браузера тогда считать "клиентом", а JavaScript код - "сервером", и называть скриптинг на JS клиент-серверным программированием, так?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin ничего не могу ответить, бо не смыслю в вебе и джаваскриптах.